# Spring autowiring list of components

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have an interface:

```
public interface IExternalCommandExecutor {
    String[] getCommandNames();
    void process(String command) throws FailedOperationException;
}
```

And two implementations(second is similar):

```
@Service
public class ExecutorImpl implements IExternalCommandExecutor {
    //some code...
}
```

And service, in which I'm using @Autowired annotation on the list of `IExternalCommandExecutor`:

```
@Service
public class ExternalCommandsService {

    @Autowired
    List<IExternalCommandExecutor> commandExecutors;

    // other code
}
```

When I'm trying to run this, I'm getting this error:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'java.util.List<com.mpcomp.entity.system.IExternalCommandExecutor>' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

Which is weird behavior for Spring. As it was mentioned in [this article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-ordering-autowired-collections/) and in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html), Spring should try to autowire all elements of `IExternalCommandExecutor` instead of trying to find bean of type `java.util.List`.

If I would change `List<IExternalCommandExecutor>` to `IExternalCommandExecutor[]`, error is quite similar:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'com.mpcomp.entity.system.IExternalCommandExecutor[]' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

I'm using Spring of version 4.3.8 RELEASE. Any help will be appreciated!

---

**Edit**
Interface and service are in the core module, and implementations of interface are in 'children' module which is depends on core module. When I moved service to this 'children' module, everything works fine!

Comment: Are all classes/interfaces in the same module?

Comment: @yinon No. Interface is in core module, service and implementation is in another module, which depends on core

Comment: can you try to autowire just one service and tell us if it is successful

Comment: @yinon sorry I sad wrong, interface and service was in the core module, and implementation in another, which depends on core. Now when I moved service to this second module, it helped!

Comment: Good, that was the main suspect... Happy it helped!

Comment: @yinon thanks :) As I understand it's not possible to autowire components in a core module from other modules?

Comment: Having core and/or children has nothing to do with autowiring, it all depends on your spring contexts and how you load / import them

Comment: @DenisDorohov basically, you need to make sure that the component classes you expect to be autowired are available to be loaded in runtime (i.e. in the classpath). Assuming you are using maven or gradle, this means  the module where you have your service with `@Autowired List<MyComponent> components;` have a dependency on the module where the components implementing `MyComponent` are. This dependency can be scoped either as `compile` or as `runtime`.